# Do grades obtained after applying to a graduate school matter?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, grades

Suppose one submits his/her application to a graduate school this November and grades for the ongoing semester are due after that. Do these grades, received after submitting the application, matter in the admission process?

Comment: I have heard anecdotal evidence of students getting their acceptances revoked from medical school due to this. What are you planning to do, get Fs across the board?

Comment: No I need to know what if people take all their easy courses before submitting their application and leave the challenging courses for afterward.

Comment: Well, as long as you put in reasonable effort, I don't see any issue. It's not like people take classes hardest to easiest in college.

Comment: This really does not make any sense your GPA in application is GPA at time of submitting the application and you can have basket of easy classes and have 4.0. BTW I did not mean getting all F. I meant reduction to B+ or A- from A's because this is still reduction in GPA.

Comment: Bear in mind that graduate admissions committees don't just look at your GPA, they look at whether you have taken challenging courses that will adequately prepare you for grad school.  If you've taken only easy courses, you'll probably be rejected no matter how good the grades are.

Comment: You're fretting too much if it's a B+ you're worried about.

Comment: _if people take all their easy courses before submitting their application_ — Those students don't get accepted.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Many graduate departments may accept your application, but require a final undergraduate transcript before you actually start your first semester there.  If your grades have seriously dropped in your last semesters, they could rescind the offer of admission, and not let you in after all.

So in short: extra good grades in your last semesters can't help you, but bad grades can hurt you.